# Create schema with custom heading

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I am creating schema, like this:

```
var MySchema = new Schema({
    good {
        name: {String, required: true},
        goodImg: {type: String, required: true}
    {
});
```

I have next stucture in database:

```
good { 
    name: "Some Name", 
    goodImg: "./path"
}
```

But how can I replace static word "good" to some more informative in my schema? For example if I want make catogories for fruit:

```
fruit {
    name: "Some fruit",
    goodImg: "./path"
}
```

or

```
vegetable {
    name: "Some vegetable",
    goodImg: "./path" 
}
```

The question is, how to rewrite my schema and make name of my object changeble? Now it is static word "good", but I want to make it more informative...

Comment: i don't quite understand what you are asking. You want to change schema name dynamically?

Comment: @Arpit Solanki Now every object with data called "good", but I want to chage "good" to another tiltles, like "fruit", "vagetable", "milk" and so on,

Comment: once the model is exported i don't think you will be able to do that

Comment: Why not just make it a field e.g. `type: String`?

Comment: @Mikey So I can make `good  {type: String, name: {type:String}, img: {type: String} }` ?

Comment: I'm saying keep it simple e.g. `new Schema({ itemType: { type: String, required: true }, name: { type: String, required: true }, img: { type: String, required: true } });` as indicated by Hanzhao. If you make your schema definition complicated, you will make other things complicated. If you really want to achieve what you want, you will have to disable [strict](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need one more attribute in your schema.

```
itemType: {type: String, required: true}
```

Put milk, vegetable or whatever descriptor you have there in *itemType*...